# How to fix serve error due to package.json missing in production only?

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, package.json, webpack-production

How can I fix the error below:

```
> ng "serve" "0.0.0.0" "--poll=2500" "--disable-host-check" "--prod=true"

WARNING Running a server with --disable-host-check is a security risk. See https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a for more information.
****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 95% emittingUnhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/web/node_modules/handsontable/package.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:461:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at LicenseExtractor.readPackageJson (/usr/src/web/node_modules/license-webpack-plugin/dist/LicenseExtractor.js:126:23)
    at LicenseExtractor.parsePackage (/usr/src/web/node_modules/license-webpack-plugin/dist/LicenseExtractor.js:23:32)
    at ModuleProcessor.processPackage (/usr/src/web/node_modules/license-webpack-plugin/dist/ModuleProcessor.js:44:46)
    at ModuleProcessor.processFile (/usr/src/web/node_modules/license-webpack-plugin/dist/ModuleProcessor.js:41:21)
    at fileCallback (/usr/src/web/node_modules/license-webpack-plugin/dist/LicenseWebpackPlugin.js:107:61)
    at moduleCallback (/usr/src/web/node_modules/license-webpack-plugin/dist/LicenseWebpackPlugin.js:114:21)
    at /usr/src/web/node_modules/license-webpack-plugin/dist/LicenseWebpackPlugin.js:126:29
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Compiler.emitCallback (/usr/src/web/node_modules/license-webpack-plugin/dist/LicenseWebpackPlugin.js:92:32)
    at next (/usr/src/web/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at /usr/src/web/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js:204:9
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.finallyHandler (/usr/src/web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/finally.js:56:23)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.tryCatcher (/usr/src/web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/src/web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
```

thrown when:

```
npm run ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 -- --poll=2500 --disable-host-check --prod=true
```

is run. But which isn't thrown when:

```
npm run ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 -- --poll=2500 --disable-host-check
```

is run?

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "retailportal-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build": "ng build --base-href /SopPortal/",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod --base-href /SopPortal/",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~5.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~5.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "~1.0.0-beta.8",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "~0.25.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~9.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "~3.2.17",
    "angular-highcharts": "5.2.8",
    "compass-sass-mixins": "0.12.7",
    "core-js": "~2.5.3",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "~2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "6.0.6",
    "numbro": "2.1.2",
    "jquery": "~3.2.1",
    "ng-bootstrap": "~1.6.3",
    "ng2-file-upload": "~1.3.0",
    "ng2-handsontable": "2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "rxjs": "~5.5.5",
    "tether": "~1.4.3",
    "ts-helpers": "~1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~5.0.0",
    "@types/highcharts": "5.0.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/jquery": "~3.2.12",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "~0.2.1",
    "moment": "~2.20.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-md5": "~1.2.0",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

and `npm ls --depth=0`:

```
# npm ls --depth=0
retailportal-web@0.0.0 /usr/src/web
+-- @angular/animations@5.1.1
+-- @angular/cdk@5.0.1
+-- @angular/cli@1.7.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.1.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.1.3
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.5
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.1.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@5.1.3
+-- @angular/http@5.1.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/material@5.0.1
+-- @angular/material-moment-adapter@5.0.3
+-- @angular/platform-browser@5.1.3
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.1.3
+-- @angular/router@5.1.3
+-- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4
+-- @ng-select/ng-select@0.25.0
+-- @ngx-translate/core@9.0.2
+-- @ngx-translate/http-loader@2.0.1
+-- @types/highcharts@5.0.16
+-- @types/jasmine@2.5.45
+-- @types/jquery@3.2.18
+-- @types/node@6.0.118
+-- angular-highcharts@5.2.8
+-- bindings@1.5.0 extraneous
+-- codelyzer@3.1.2
+-- compass-sass-mixins@0.12.7
+-- core-js@2.5.7
+-- enhanced-resolve@3.3.0
+-- font-awesome@4.7.0
+-- hammerjs@2.0.8
+--  extraneous error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/web/node_modules/handsontable/package.json
+-- highcharts@6.0.6
+-- jasmine-core@2.6.2
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.1.0
+-- jquery@3.2.1
+-- karma@1.7.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.1.1
+-- karma-cli@1.0.1
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.2
+-- karma-remap-istanbul@0.2.2
+-- moment@2.20.1
+-- ng-bootstrap@1.6.3
+-- ng2-file-upload@1.3.0
+-- ng2-handsontable@2.0.0
+-- node-sass@4.14.1
+-- numbro@2.1.2
+-- protractor@5.1.2
+-- rxjs@5.5.12
+-- tether@1.4.7
+-- ts-helpers@1.1.2
+-- ts-md5@1.2.7
+-- ts-node@3.0.4
+-- tslint@5.3.2
+-- typescript@2.4.2
`-- zone.js@0.8.29

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^4.0.0, required by ng2-handsontable@2.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@5.0.5, required by @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.5
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0, required by codelyzer@3.1.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@^4.0.0, required by ng2-handsontable@2.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@5.1.1, required by @angular/animations@5.1.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0, required by codelyzer@3.1.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^4.0.0, required by ng2-handsontable@2.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^4.0.0, required by ng2-handsontable@2.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/material@5.0.3, required by @angular/material-moment-adapter@5.0.3
npm ERR! extraneous: handsontable /usr/src/web/node_modules/handsontable
npm ERR! error in /usr/src/web/node_modules/handsontable: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/web/node_modules/handsontable/package.json'
npm ERR! extraneous: bindings@1.5.0 /usr/src/web/node_modules/bindings
```

node & npm versions:

```
# node --version
v14.2.0
# npm --version
6.14.4
#
```

also tried with node 6 to no avail.

the package `handsontable` is supplied independent from npm.

Comment: Wow.. that’s an old Angular version.. anyway, it seems that something is either wrong with ‘handsontable’ package or that version is not compatible with your (very old) angular version. Did you try to re-install that package?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes I am copying it statically from a zipped file.

Comment: Wait... what do you mean? Is this not an actual npm package?

Comment: @MikeOne I don't know its details. I am copying a handsontable folder to node_modules folder. Which has .js .css min full etc files. ng2-handsontable is supposed to work with it. It does too, in debug mode.

Comment: That is not just going to work. I suspect it is this thing you need to do: npm i @handsontable/angular. You cannot simply copy anything to node_modules like that I’m afraid.

Comment: Try setting extractLicenses to false in your angular.json file for prod configuration

Comment: How are you copying the package? Can you post your script or code that's doing the copying?

Comment: @NatusDrew There's currently no script. I'm manually copy pasting. But this is happening in the track of improving the build.

Comment: @David I'm not sure how to do that. There's angular-cli.json as opposed to angular.json. I'll let the results be known if I could manage to do as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Oh right you are using angular 5. Try passing `--extractLicenses=false` to your `ng build`. Not sure if this is allowed in that version though

Comment: @David That seems to do it. Thanks! Although I have no idea what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build in prod mode, angular tries to extract licenses from the 3rd party libs that you use into a `3rdpartylicenses.txt` file. For that, it needs looking at `package.json` files.

Since you put your `handontable` package manually in your `node_modules`, it's missing `package.json`.

What you should really do is install `handontable` with npm (specify the version if needed)

```
npm add -S handsontable
```

A workaround is to disable extracting the licenses, by passing a flag when building

```
npm run ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll=2500 --disable-host-check --prod=true --extractLicenses=false
```